# How to tell what version of `pdftk` you're running?

Tags: pdftk

`pdftk -v` doesn't do the trick. Neither does `pdftk -h`. That just fills the screen past the available history with a manual. But it does not tell me what version I'm running.

Any ideas?

I'm running Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my WinXP (and Ubuntu) `pdftk --version` works just fine.
e.g. Ubuntu
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can also use `more` if the "screen fills", as you said:

```
pdftk --help | more
```

The very first line of the output should hold the version information you are looking for.

```
pdftk --version
```

should also work just fine on Windows.